# Spark Reading data frames from different schema directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My spark program has to read  from a directory, This directory has data of different schema

> Dir/subdir1/files
>   1,10, Alien
>   1,11, Bob
>
> Dir/subdir2/files
>   2,blue, 123, chicago
>   2,red, 34, Dallas

Around 50 more directories with different schemas.

My spark job has to read data from all these directories and generate a file merging this files as shown below

> 1, 10, Alien;
>   1, 11, Bob;
>   2, blue, 123,chicago;
>   2, red, 34, Dallas;

Spark data frame expects schema to be same in all directories. is there any way I can read all these files of different schema and merge into single file using spark

Comment: What is the format of the data ? If it is parquet you can use spark parquet schema merging.

Comment: They are parquet files. But all the files have different schema.

Answer (score 4):

With parquet and different schema there are 2 strategy that I know of

1. If the schema is compatible you can use mergeSchema

   ```
   spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("Dir/")
   ```

Documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery

2. If the columns are incompatible type you need to read individual directories then you need to convert them to jsonRDD with

   ```
   df.toJSON
   ```

and then union all the jsonRDD

```
   df.toJSON.union(df2.toJSON)
```

followed by converting back to parquet

```
   spark.read.json(finalJsonRDD)
```